# Get the latest values in each column in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, merge, ms-access-2016, ms-access-query

Please consider this table in MS Access:

```
Id       Year       Month         F1         F2         F3         F4
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1        2020         1           A          B          1          2
1        2020         2           AA      
1        2020         3                      BB         11
2        2020         1                                 3          4
2        2020         2           F          G
```

I want to have this result:

```
Id       F1         F2         F3         F4
-----------------------------------------------
1        AA         BB         11         2
2        F          G          3          4
```

I want the latest value in each column and merge them in one row for each `Id`.

How can I achieve this result using a query in MS Access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Id,
    (SELECT TOP 1 F1 FROM test t1 WHERE t1.Id = t.Id AND F1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [Year] DESC, [Month] DESC) AS F1,
    (SELECT TOP 1 F2 FROM test t1 WHERE t1.Id = t.Id AND F2 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [Year] DESC, [Month] DESC) AS F2,
    (SELECT TOP 1 F3 FROM test t1 WHERE t1.Id = t.Id AND F3 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [Year] DESC, [Month] DESC) AS F3,
    (SELECT TOP 1 F4 FROM test t1 WHERE t1.Id = t.Id AND F4 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY [Year] DESC, [Month] DESC) AS F4
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Id 
    FROM test
) t
```

If the empty cells in your example are empty strings instead of NULL, then the condition in the subquery will be `F1 <> "`.